# Upload a Resource File via FTP using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, ftp

I am working on a project (which uses only static methods). Now I want to upload a File to my FTP-Server. The uploading-Process is not the problem (Apache Commons). But this File I want to upload is a resource File which is in my Project.

I export this Project to a runnable JAR file.

Now question one: WHERE in my project do I have to store this resource file to be able to upload it (and to be sure it gets also exported into the runnable JAR)?

And question two: HOW can I access this File into my Java Program?

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: you need to get the resource, unzip it, search for the file, check it, and then, upload it. Can you expand on "my App only works with static context.." cheers

Comment: I've read your question at least 3 times, but your concrete problem is very hard to understand. It look like as if you mixed/confused some basic concepts/terms.

Comment: I've just updated my Answer :) Hope it is more understandable...

Comment: Ah Sorry @PbxMan, I meant I updated the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the solution:

```
try {
    InputStream is = new Object(){}.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works, if the File "myfile.txt" is located into the source Folder (`src`) of my Eclipse project. I forgot the leading slash before...

Thanks all for help!